# Vanishing conjugate momenta

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, momentum, geodesics

I have an AdS-Vaidya black hole metric given by,

$$ds^2 = \frac{1}{z^2} \left( -f(v,z) dv^2 - 2 dv dz + dx^2\right)$$

where $f(v,z) = 1 - m(v) z^2$ and $m(v)$ is mass as a function of $v$. The coordinate $z$ is the bulk coordinate where $r = 1/z$ is the radial coordinate. The coordinate $v$ is the Eddington-Finkelstein coordinate $v = t + \int \frac{dz}{f(v,z)}$. The details are not too important I guess since the question is quite general and does not necessarily have to be a black hole spacetime.

I want to calculate the area functional $A$ as (in terms of an affine parameter $\tau$),

$$A = \int_{\tau_0}^{\tau_1} d\tau \frac{1}{z} \sqrt{-f(v,z) \dot{v}^2 - 2 \dot{v} \dot{z} + \dot{x}^2}, \qquad L = \frac{\sqrt{-f(v,z) \dot{v}^2 - 2 \dot{v} \dot{z} + \dot{x}^2}}{z}$$

The boundary conditions are $v(\tau_0) = t$, $\dot{v}(\tau_1) = 0$, $z(\tau_0) = \epsilon$, $\dot{z}(\tau_1) = 0$, $x(\tau_0) = \epsilon$, $\dot{x}(\tau_1) = \dot{v}(\tau_1)\;$ where $t \in [\epsilon, 1]$ is time and we can take it to have some numerical value and $\epsilon$ is a cutoff parameter that is small, say $10^{-2}$.

In the end, the Euler-Lagrange equation should be calculated and solved, and so we first need to calculate the conjugate momenta

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{v}} = \frac{-f \dot{v} - \dot{z}}{z \sqrt{-f(v,z) \dot{v}^2 - 2 \dot{v} \dot{z} + \dot{x}^2} }$$

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{z}} = \frac{ -\dot{v}}{z \sqrt{-f(v,z) \dot{v}^2 - 2 \dot{v} \dot{z} + \dot{x}^2} }$$

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{z}} = \frac{ \dot{x}}{z \sqrt{-f(v,z) \dot{v}^2 - 2 \dot{v} \dot{z} + \dot{x}^2} }$$

Since the Lagrangian $L$ does not depend on $x$ explicitly, its conjugate momenta should be conserved.

$$\frac{ \dot{x}}{z \sqrt{-f(v,z) \dot{v}^2 - 2 \dot{v} \dot{z} + \dot{x}^2} } = C  = \text{constant}$$

$$\dot{x} = C z \sqrt{-f(v,z) \dot{v}^2 - 2 \dot{v} \dot{z} + \dot{x}^2}$$

Here is the question, one way to determine the integration constant $C$ is by looking at the boundary point $\dot{x}(\tau_1) = \dot{v}(\tau_1) = 0$ and $\dot{z}(\tau_1) = 0$. However, this still does not tell me anything about $C$ since it will become an equation like,

$$0 = C \cdot 0$$

One way to resolve this is by looking at the functional $A$, since we have an arbitrary affine parameter $\tau$ we can always choose the integrated such that,

$$\frac{\sqrt{-f(v,z) \dot{v}^2 - 2 \dot{v} \dot{z} + \dot{x}^2}}{z} = 1$$

This will lead to the equation,

$$\frac{ \dot{x}}{z^2} = C, \qquad z \neq 0$$

where when we apply the boundary condition $\dot{x}(\tau_1) = \dot{v}(\tau_1) = 0$, we get $C=0$. So it means that $\dot{x}$ is not only vanishing on the boundary, but all throughout.

My concern is, I want to make the equations as simple as possible so that I don't have to solve three complicated coupled nonlinear equations. If I can find a way to eliminate $x$ it would be helpful in my calculations. However, what does it mean when the conjugate momenta vanishes as in the problem I'm dealing with (of course the obvious idea that comes to mind is $\dot{x} = 0$ implies $x = \;$constant)? Is there any deeper meaning I'm missing? Is my derivation of $C=0$ consistent?